# Valor aparece e some após o click- Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, array, input

Boa noite, fiz uma lógica em javascript dos inputs receberem o valor de um array, tudo certo porém, quando clica no botão para acontecer o evento os valores aparecem e somem do input rapidamente, segugue o código, Obrigado.

```
<script>
var codigo = "23794130047008001672190051686005178110000010890"

var metade = Math.floor(codigo.length / 8);
var seis = Math.floor(codigo.length / 7);
var um = Math.floor(codigo.length/47);
var rest = Math.floor(codigo.length/3)

var res = codigo.substr(0,metade) + " ," + codigo.substr(5,metade)  + " ," + codigo.substr(10,metade)
+ " ," + codigo.substr(15,seis) + " ," + codigo.substr(21,metade) + " ," + codigo.substr(26,seis)
+ " ," + codigo.substr(32,um) + " ," + codigo.substr(33,rest);


var div = res.split(" ,")

function separar(){
    let teste = document.getElementsByTagName("input")

    for(i =0; i< teste.length; i++){
    teste[i].value = div[i]
    console.log(teste[i].value = div[i])
    }
}



</script>


<form id="form" >


    <label>Digite o código</label>
<br/><button onclick="separar()">Separar</button>
<br/>
<br/>



    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>



</form>
```

Comment: Qual a ideia? cada input ficar com um valor?

Comment: Cada input recebe um valor do array 'div', quando coloco o window.onload na frente da function os valores já iniciam corretamente nos inputs, mas sem, quando clico, aparece rapidamente e some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por padrão, o `<button>` assume o `type` como `submit`, quando dentro de um formulário. O que está acontecendo é que, ao clicar no botão o evento submit é disparado e então o formulário é "enviado" fazendo com que a página seje limpa.

Adicione o `type="button"` ao botão

```js
var codigo = "23794130047008001672190051686005178110000010890"

var metade = Math.floor(codigo.length / 8);
var seis = Math.floor(codigo.length / 7);
var um = Math.floor(codigo.length/47);
var rest = Math.floor(codigo.length/3)

var res = codigo.substr(0,metade) + " ," + codigo.substr(5,metade)  + " ," + codigo.substr(10,metade)
+ " ," + codigo.substr(15,seis) + " ," + codigo.substr(21,metade) + " ," + codigo.substr(26,seis)
+ " ," + codigo.substr(32,um) + " ," + codigo.substr(33,rest);

var div = res.split(" ,")

function separar(){
    let teste = document.getElementsByTagName("input")

    for(i =0; i< teste.length; i++){
        teste[i].value = div[i]
        //console.log(teste[i].value = div[i])
    }
}
```

```html
<form id="form" >
    <label>Digite o código</label>
<br/><button type="button" onclick="separar()">Separar</button>
<br/>
<br/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
</form>
```

Para pegar o código através de um `input`, adicione um `input` **fora** do formulário com um `id` pra ficar mais fácil de pegar depois. Adicione todo o código de separação dentro da função `separar()`. Para pegar os inputs use o `id` do `form` como referência para poder pegar todos os `inputs` de dentro dele. Segue o código de exemplo

```js
function separar(){
    var codigo = document.getElementById("codigo").value;

    var metade = Math.floor(codigo.length / 8);
    var seis = Math.floor(codigo.length / 7);
    var um = Math.floor(codigo.length/47);
    var rest = Math.floor(codigo.length/3)

    var res = codigo.substr(0,metade) + " ," + codigo.substr(5,metade)  + " ," + codigo.substr(10,metade)
+ " ," + codigo.substr(15,seis) + " ," + codigo.substr(21,metade) + " ," + codigo.substr(26,seis)
+ " ," + codigo.substr(32,um) + " ," + codigo.substr(33,rest);

    var div = res.split(" ,")
    let teste = document.getElementById("form").getElementsByTagName("input")

    for(i =0; i< teste.length; i++){
        teste[i].value = div[i]
        //console.log(teste[i].value = div[i])
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="codigo">
<form id="form" >
    <label>Digite o código</label>
<br/><button type="button" onclick="separar()">Separar</button>
<br/>
<br/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Cara muito obrigado !! só uma pergunta se eu quisesse ao invés de definir esse valor fixo, pegar de um input por exemplo, como faria ? estou tentando com queryselector mas da esse erro: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: @israel Adicionei à resposta. Caso considere essa resposta como adequada, não se esqueça de marca-la como correta :)

Comment: Perfeito !! Muito Obrigado